# SurfaceView Rect objects get deleted android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, surfaceview, scaling, rect

I'm developing a **draw view with multiple rectangles which can be re-sized and dragged** (on a camera preview).
I think I got it to work. But the thing is, the rectangles appeared to be get deleted some how. **they sometimes disappear from the view and get removed from the Rect array** while dragging or resizing. Can somebody point out the bug?? thanks in advanced.

**here is my DrawView class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class DrawView extends SurfaceView {

    private Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    private List<Rect> Rectangles;
    private float x_axis;
    private float y_axis;
    private boolean found;
    private String TAG="DrawView";
    private Rect tempRect;



    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Create out paint to use for drawing
        textPaint.setARGB(255, 200, 0, 0);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        textPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        textPaint.setAlpha(200);
        /* This call is necessary, or else the 
         * draw method will not be called. 
         */
        Rectangles=new ArrayList<Rect>();

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }


    public void setCoordinates (float x1, float y1) {

        x_axis=x1;
        y_axis=y1;

        Rectangles.add(new Rect(Math.round(x_axis)-150, Math.round(y_axis)-70, Math.round(x_axis)+150, Math.round(y_axis)+70));
        // indicate view should be redrawn
        postInvalidate();

    }

    public void tryDrag(float x, float y){

        if(tempRect!=null){
            tempRect.set(Math.round(x-tempRect.width()/2),Math.round(y+tempRect.height()/2)
                    ,Math.round(x+tempRect.width()/2),Math.round(y-tempRect.height()/2));
            postInvalidate();
        }

    }
    public void DrawNow(){
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void   animateDrag(float x, float y){
        found=false;
        tempRect=null;
        for(Rect R: Rectangles){

            if(R.contains(Math.round(x), Math.round(y))){
                found=true;
                tempRect =R;
                break;
            }

        }


        if(found){

            Log.d(TAG, "inside a rectange");        
        }

    }

    public void doScale(float x, float y){
        if(tempRect!=null){

            int tempWidth=Math.round((tempRect.width()*x)/2);
            int tempHeight=Math.round((tempRect.height()*y)/2);

            tempRect.set(tempRect.centerX()-tempWidth,tempRect.centerY()+tempHeight,tempRect.centerX()+tempWidth,tempRect.centerY()-tempHeight);

            postInvalidate();

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        // A Simple Text Render to test the display

        for(Rect R: Rectangles)
            canvas.drawRect(R.left,R.top,R.right,R.bottom, textPaint);


    }
}
```

**here is my code part from the Activity class**

```
    private float scaleFactorY;
    private float scaleFactorX;

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 


        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if(mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) return false;
        //let the ScaleGestureDetector try first

        // if scale detector is not in progress 
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " ); 
        if(scaling==0)
        dv.animateDrag(event.getX(),event.getY());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: "); 


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        if(scaling>0) return false;
        dv.tryDrag(e2.getX(),e2.getY());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress: ");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: ");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: ");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: ");

        int pointerIndex0 = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(0));
        // Get the 1st pointer's current position
        float x0 = event.getX(pointerIndex0);
        float y0 = event.getY(pointerIndex0);
        Log.d(TAG, "X0= "+x0+ " Y0=" + y0);

        if(RactangleCount<5){

            dv.setCoordinates(x0, y0);

            if (safeToTakePicture && prvw) {

                ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(dv);

                safeToTakePicture = false;
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback); 
                prvw=false; 

            }

            RactangleCount++;
        }


        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG,"on Drag");
        // dv.animateDrag(event.getX(),event.getY());

        //dv.tryDrag(e2.getX(),e2.getY());
        return false;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaling++;
        Log.d(TAG,"on scale");

            scaleFactorX= detector.getCurrentSpanX()/detector.getPreviousSpanX();
            scaleFactorY= detector.getCurrentSpanY()/detector.getPreviousSpanY();
            Log.d(TAG,"on" + "Xfactor"+scaleFactorX+"Yfactor"+scaleFactorY);



        dv.doScale(scaleFactorX,scaleFactorY);

        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        scaling=1;
        Log.d(TAG,"on scale begin");


        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG,"on scale end");

        scaling=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solved..!**
if anyone has a same kind of a problem, the answer is **check the rectangle boundaries**. The top y coordinates always should be smaller than bottom y coordinates. Otherwise the surface view may give unexpected results.

this is the line with an error.

```
 tempRect.set(tempRect.centerX()-tempWidth,tempRect.centerY()+tempHeight,tempRect.centerX()+tempWidth,tempRect.centerY()-tempHeight);
```

it should be corrected as

```
tempRect.set(tempRect.centerX()-tempWidth,tempRect.centerY()-tempHeight,tempRect.centerX()+tempWidth,tempRect.centerY()+tempHeight);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you have made my day.